# How to damp the velocity of an object only in one axis in Box2d?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I want to damp the velocity of a ball linearly on the x-axis. but when applying linear damping on the ball, the damping also applies in the y-axis which makes it look like its floating.

I tried to refer the [Manual](https://box2d.org/manual.pdf) but it says: "Damping parameters should be between 0 and infinity, with 0 meaning no damping, and infinity
meaning full damping. Normally you will use a damping value between 0 and 0.1. **I generally do not use
linear damping because it makes bodies look like they are floating**."

So how can I damp the ball in the axis while there is no damping in the y-axis

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will have to implement the dampening yourself. something along the lines of:

```
private static float dampening;

//called every frame
public void dampen(float deltaT){
    Vector2 vel = ball.getBody().getLinearVelocity();
    float newX = vel.x * (1 - delta * dampening);
    vel.x = newX;
    ball.getBody().setLinearVelocity(vel);
}
```

The comment about Dampening looking floaty refers to the fact, that the velocity never reaches 0 this way. So bodys that are only slowed down by dampening look somewhat like hovercraft.

To avoid that you can reduce the velocity by a fixed amount somewhat like friction.

My example would be better if the dampening was applyed as a force to the body instead of setting the velocity, but the math becomes more complicated.

Here is an example of my custom implementation of friction in my top-down game. It works pretty good so far:

```
    // Linar Gleitreibung
default void applyLinearFriction(float deltaT) {
    float fGleit = getFriction().getLinearFriction() * getBody().getMass();
    Vector2 curVel = getBody().getLinearVelocity();
    Vector2 wGleit;
    float fMax;
    // apply friction to full velocity
    wGleit = new Vector2(-curVel.x, -curVel.y);
    fMax = curVel.len() * getBody().getMass() / deltaT;

    if (fGleit > fMax) {
        wGleit.setLength(fMax);
    } else {
        wGleit.setLength(fGleit);
    }
    getBody().applyForceToCenter(wGleit, true);
}
```

sorry im too tired to write that into a clean example right now ;)